# How to make VS Code not to put { on new line in c#

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have installed VS Code on Debian 8.5 and installed C# Ext.

i need to force VS Code(visual studio code) to format code as:

```
if (condition) {
}
```

and not (following ugly style)

```
if ( condition)
{
}
```

there is settings for `typescript` and `javascript`, but nothing for `c#`.

Also , I'm using vs code on debian 8.5

Answer (score -1):

It can be achieved using `Visual Studio Code Format'.

in plugins, search and install it.

more information [Visual Studio Code Format](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ryannaddy.vscode-format) page